# Pandas dataframe to dictionary with row index as value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

How can I convert a pandas df to a dictionary that uses its row index as the value? For example, say I have df with a single column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'ID': [3823, 4724,6233,2438],
                  })
```

which gives me:

```
   ID
0  3823
1  4724
2  6233
3  2438
```

and I want to return a dictionary that will be:

```
{3832: 0,  4724: 1, 6233: 2, 2438: 3}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `{y:x for x, y in zip(df.index, df["ID"])}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use to_dict() and dictionary comprehension as follows.

```
{v:k for k, v in df['ID'].to_dict().items()}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This almost works, but returns:
{2438: 3, 3823: 0, 4724: 1, 6233: 2}
do you know how i can have it return the dictionary in row-index order? like:
{3832: 0,  4724: 1, 6233: 2, 2438: 3}

Comment: @jamessmith just do `df['ID'].to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ret_dict = {df.loc[index, 'ID']:index for index in df.index}
```

Output:

```
{3823: 0, 4724: 1, 6233: 2, 2438: 3}
```